# difficulty with final admob configuration/implementation libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, admob

I've been trying to include some ads in my app using AdMob. It all launches ok so i assume i have the library added correctly etc. I followed a tutorial that was over a year old (Brent Aureli on youtube) becoz that was all i could find relative to LibGDX.

It seems to try to pull the ad in , but can't display it. I can't make much more sense out of the log and would love if someone can help me out.

As a note, my game is in debug version (of course as i'm still developing it in Android Studio - but v1.0 is available on Play Store), i've added the Test Device as per the log. Usually (ie. before i added the adView code) the intro music plays right from the start. This still happens but as soon as i get the message on phone saying "signing into Google..." and the subsequent failure message (which is normal as its in debug) the music now stops and doesnt start again until i press my Play Game button.

I'm currently doing everything inside AndroidLauncher.

Here is the log:
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {d618180}
I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk succesful, fd=61 off=43108 len=3029
I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:62 off:229484 len:1089587
W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(331)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
I/AndroidLauncher: ad loaded...
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
D/GameHelper: GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=RC_RESOLVE, resp=SIGN_IN_FAILED
D/GameHelper: GameHelper: onAR: responseCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, so giving up.
W/GameHelper: disconnect() called when client was already disconnected.
D/GameHelper: GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (error)
I/AndroidInput: sensor listener setup
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
I/AndroidGraphics: resumed
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@36075376 time:451983293
I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
I/AndroidGraphics: paused
I/AndroidInput: sensor listener tear down
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed meshes/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed textures/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed cubemap/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed shaders/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed buffers/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: destroyed
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/GameHelper: GameHelper: onStop
D/GameHelper: GameHelper: Client already disconnected when we got onStop.

and my code:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener, GoogInterface{
private final String TAG = "AndroidLauncher";
private GameHelper gameHelper;
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
FlapTurdGame game;





protected AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game = new FlapTurdGame(this);
    if (gameHelper == null) {
        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
        gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    }
    loginGPGS();

    // make a new relative layout (as per Brents tutorial) for AdMob
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    View gameView = initializeForView(game, config);
    gameView.setMinimumHeight(200);
    layout.addView(gameView);


    // create the new AdView and pass it this (it takes an activity but calls it context - i dunno why yet!)
    adView = new AdView(this);

    // set the adListener for the adView:
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.i(TAG, "ad loaded..." );
        }
    });

    // set size and Ad Id for banner ad
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9900639686681371/7970613041");

    // create an adrequest builder
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    builder.addTestDevice("42BC38E35388C24799529CF0FA59830A");
    // sets layout of advert to wrap to width and height:
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // add the banner ad to our layout with the adParams:
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    adView.loadAd(builder.build());



    setContentView(layout);

    gameHelper.setup(this);
    initialize(game, config);

}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}

@Override
public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}

@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }

}

@Override
public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_top_scorers_world), score);
}

@Override
public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
    Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
}

@Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_top_scorers_world)), 100);
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}

@Override
public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}

@Override
public void onShowAchievementsRequested() {

}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {

}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i actually found the answer.  I had to move my      initialize(game, config); call in AndroidLauncher to be BEFORE the call setContentView(layout);

Comment: you can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark